# glassfish 4.0 jpa resource

Tags: jpa, deployment, glassfish

I try to deploy my application but I still get deployment errors. I created connection pool succesfully (I can even create entities from tables using JPA Tools in Eclipse).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

As you can see I've also created a JDBC Resource in Glassfish admin panel called sellyourthingres. When I use "sellyourthingres" instead of "sellyourthing" in persitance.xml nothing changes and i got exactly the same errors (with different name of course). Choosing JTA/JTA(default) doesn't change anything.

What should I do?

Comment: include your persistence.xml, ensure you are setting the data-source correctly.

Comment: Go to your JDBC connection pool page for `sellyourthing` and click Ping. That should give you a more useful error message. As well as determining whether the error is a Glassfish config error, or an application error.